# Difficulty in understanding the solution to N = min{n>= 2: Un > Un-1}

Tags: probability

It is Example 3.28 on page 124 in Ross's book (Introduction to Probability Models-11th edition)

Let $U_1$,$U_2$,... be a sequence of independent uniform $(0,1)$ random variables, and let $N$ = min{n >= 2: $U_n$ > $U_{n-1}$}

That is, N is the index of the first uniform random variables that is larger than its immediate predecessor.

The Solution Says:

It is easy to find the distribution of N. Since all $n!$ possible orderings of $U_1$,...,$U_n$ are equally likely, we have

P(N > n) = P{$U_1$ > $U_2$ > ... > $U_n$} = $1/n!$

My Questions:

1. Is "all $n!$ possible orderings" the sample space? Is the sequence
       [$U_1 = U_2 = ... = U_n$] in the sample space?

   ```
   I think the sample space contains cases where at least 2 of them 
   have the same value. I.E. in case of 2 Bernoulli variables the
   sample space is ([1,1],[1,0],[0,1],[0,0])
   ```
2. Why P{$U_1$ > $U_2$ > ... > $U_n$} = $1/n!$?

   ```
   Is n in P(N > n) countable or not countable? Does that really matters?
   My example: [1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]
   P(N > 2) = 2/6 ([2,1,3],[3,1,2])
   [3,2,1] this one is very strange
   ```

Your help will be great appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the $U_i$'s are *continuous* uniform variables, the case where any of them are equal (which would mess up the nice combinatorics, you're right) has probability $0$, and can thus be excluded from any calculation of probability. At least until you start conditioning on events with probability $0$, which we aren't doing.

As for why $P\{U_1 > U_2 > \ldots > U_n\} = 1/n!$, consider rewriting the situation from

> Pick $U_1$, then pick $U_2$, then ..., then pick $U_n$

to

> Pick $n$ random numbers. Then assign each of those numbers, randomly, to each of the random variables $U_1, \ldots,U_n$

We see clearly in the last case that the probability that $U_1$ gets assigned the largest number, $U_2$ the second largest, and so on, is $1/n!$.

Comment: Thanks.  "the case where any of them are equal (which would mess up the nice combinatorics, you're right) has probability 0, and can thus be excluded",  Is this by definition for continuous I.I.D. variables? Those cases are excluded from the sample space?

Comment: Yes. For any finite collection of continuous, independent variables (assuming all of their pdf's are finite at all points, so no single value has positive probability), the probability that they are all distinct is $1$. So unless you're calculating a probability with condition (and the probability of the condition is $0$), then you may safely ignore those cases.

Comment: @evergreenhomeland They are not excluded as events that can happen (i.e. $\{U_1=U_2\}$ is not necessarily empty) but - as Arthur says - they do not play a part when it comes to calculation of the relevant probabilities. It is even possible (but not necessary and cumbersome) to construct a new probability space in which the events are really excluded (i.e. $\{U_i=U_j\}=\varnothing$ if $i\neq j$), while all relevant probabilities stay the same.

Comment: I see. Is that addressed in Measure theory? Do you notice the last line ([3,2,1] this one is very strange) in the second question? In case the n is countable,there is always a special one,which values of Xis' are arranged in decreasing order with the smallest at the tail. This one does not meet the constraint (Un > Un-1).